# SetPropertyListener and Pageflow Scope on popUp ADF

Tags: dialog, popup, oracle-adf

in a task flow I have the button

```
<af:button id="b2" icon="/images.gif" rendered="#{not isUserReadOnly}">
                  <af:setPropertyListener from="#{row.Id}" to="#{pageFlowScope.Id}" type="action"/>
                  <af:showPopupBehavior popupId=":::pu1" triggerType="click"/>
                </af:button>
```

and on the same jsff at the end

```
<af:popup childCreation="deferred" autoCancel="disabled" id="pu1">
  <af:dialog id="d1" title="title" modal="true" stretchChildren="first"
             dialogListener="#{backingBeanScope.SettlementBacking.onOKunsettle}" contentHeight="100"
             contentWidth="220">
    <af:outputText value="#{viewcontrollerBundle.text} (Id: #{pageFlowScope.Id})" id="ot11"/>
  </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```

Althought

```
String Id = AdfUtils.getPageFlowScope("Id").toString();
```

in my java bean, retrieves the correct Id, the popup shows only my first choice no matter that I select a different row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found 2 answers on the following posts

- [not working on with child creation deferr](http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/02/not-working-on-with-childcreationdeferr.html)
- [fails when used with for buttons action](http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/03/fails-when-used-with-for-buttons-action.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `af:showPopupBehavior` will suppress the server event, that means `<af:setPropertyListener from="#{row.Id}" to="#{pageFlowScope.Id}" type="action"/>` will not be executed .

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_showPopupBehavior.html

-- Cancels Client Events

So, programmatically launch the popup instead of using `af:showPopupBehavior`.